# SQL ending with certain letter -> strange behaviour?

Tags: sql, db2

i've got a simple sql question:
I want to get all Customers(more precise: their name and their balance) working in a sector ending with E. I Want to order my results alphabetically by name. Therefore my query is:

```
SELECT Name,Balance FROM customer WHERE sector LIKE '%E' ORDER BY Name
```

, which is giving me false results.
I tested it by looking up which sectors exist:

```
SELECT Distinct(Sector) FROM Kunde
```

giving me:

```
Sector  
----------
AUTOMOBILE
BUILDING  
FURNITURE 
HOUSEHOLD 
MACHINERY
```

Now i tried using a query like

```
SELECT Distinct(Sector) FROM customer WHERE Sector LIKE '%E'
```

only giving me:

```
Sector 
----------
AUTOMOBILE
```

It's probably me being stupid here, but why w'ont the last query give me AUTOMOBILE and FURNITURE? I don't see the problem. I'm using DB2 if thats important.
Thank you!

Comment: if there's spaces at the end of those strings, e.g. `FURNITURE[space]`, then `%E` won't catch that. do a `select sector, length(sector)` (or whatever db2's string length function is) to see if the char counts match what you think they should be.

Comment: Do you have spaces, or other non-rendering characters at the end of `FURNITURE`?

Comment: Maybe a forgotten space at the end of `FURNITURE`?  If there is a `TRIM` function you can try `SELECT Distinct(Sector) FROM customer WHERE TRIM(Sector) LIKE '%E'`.

Comment: First you are selecting from `Kunde` table and then `customer`, perhaps doing something wrong there? Try: `SELECT Distinct(Sector) FROM Kunde WHERE Sector Like '%E'`

Comment: whoops sorry, i forgot to translate Kunde once. Didn't think of spaces at the end, yeah that did the trick, thank you all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In case of trailing spaces, remove it :

```
SELECT Distinct(Sector) 
FROM customer 
WHERE RTRIM(Sector) LIKE '%E'
```